# How do I design a class containing properties from lookup tables?

Tags: c#, oop, object

*Some context: This pertains to my budding desire to build multilayer web applications with:*

1. C# ASP.NET web forms
2. C# POCO business objects
3. Some kind of DAL... SQL (or maybe EF4 if I can figure it out)

*I wouldn't really want a response which has my presentation layer talking directly to EF entities, for instance.*

I've been doing my own web development with C# ASP.NET & SQL for 10 years but I am still a total rookie when it comes to formal OOAD. I've been pursuing this skill with a passion lately, but I'm still new at it and there is something I can't quite wrap my head around. I'm hoping someone can explain it in a way that brings an epiphany:

Let's say I create a web application that manages **People** in some way, and my Person object must possess a properties such as FirstName, LastName, HairColor, EyeColor, Ethnicity, StateOrProvince, etc. I'm using SQL Server for persistence... so common sense would dictate that the respective fields in the People table are all foreign keys:

```
FirstName varchar(50)
LastName varchar(50)
HairColor tinyint
EyeColor tinyint
Ethnicity tinyint
StateOrProvince tinyint
```

Clearly this means that I have corresponding lookup tables for each of those fields (i.e. HairColors table, EyeColors table, Ethnicities table, etc.) and each of these lookup tables has an ID and a name. Of course the Name field in these lookup tables will be JOINed with my People data whenever I want to display anything useful about a Person.

Some key features of the site would be:

**1.)** Enumerate People in a Gridview (FirstName, LastName, HairColor, EyeColor, Ethnicity, StateOrProvince)

**2.)** Show an individual Person's details on a read-only page (FirstName, LastName, HairColor, EyeColor, Ethnicity, StateOrProvince)

**3.)** Allow a user to update an individual Person's data on an update page (FirstName, LastName, HairColor, EyeColor, Ethnicity, StateOrProvince)

**Case #1**
If I was enumerating a collection of Person objects in a gridview... each Person instance would need to display its HairColor, EyeColor, Ethnicity, StateOrProvince properties **as strings** to be meaningful (i.e. the Name field from the SQL lookup table, not its ID). Clearly my SQL sproc would have some JOINs to give me the appropriate string data I need to fill these text properties in each Person instance.

**Case #2**
Again my sproc would have a JOIN to bring back the human readable property names **as strings**, and I would display them in read only Label controls using something like myPerson.HairColor, myPerson.EyeColor, etc.

**Case #3**
Here I'd be showing a page with dropdown lists for each of these properties (i.e. value=HairColorId, Text=HairColorName). My immediate instinct here would be to **use the IDs** of each property (something like myPerson.HairColorId) in order to loop through the DDL items and select a value which represents the hair color that the People table currently holds for this Person. If the user selected something different in any of the property DDLs, I'd need to pass the appropriate SelectedId values to an UPDATE sproc, and modify the values in the People table for this particular Person.

## So that leads me to the ultimate question:

How do I best design a Person object such that it contains both the ID and Name for HairColor, EyeColor, Ethnicity, StateOrProvince so I can subsequently use **the Name** when **displaying** information, but **the ID** for initializing the update DDL controls... and ultimately processing **updates**?

As I've reflected on this... I have come to the conclusion that I need to create classes to represent the HairColor, EyeColor, Ethnicity, StateOrProvince properties.

Then my Person class, instead of being something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }

    int HairColorId { get; set; }
    string HairColorName { get; set; }

    int EyeColorId { get; set; }
    string EyeColorName { get; set; }

    int StateOrProvinceId { get; set; }
    string StateOrProvinceName { get; set; }
    string StateOrProvinceCode { get; set; }
}
```

Would instead be expanded into something like this:

```
public class HairColor
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EyeColor
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class StateOrProvince
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    HairColor HairColor { get; set; }
    EyeColor EyeColor { get; set; }
    StateOrProvince StateOrProvince { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        // how do I initialize a Person from a SQL data row?

    }
}
```

But then if my Person class does look like the above... how on earth do I best initialize it (whether individually or in a collection) from a given row of data I get back from a SQL query? I seem to recall that I shouldn't be newing things up in a constructor (i.e. this.HairColor = new HairColor(dr["HairColorId"), dr["HairColorName"];)... so I'm wondering how a call to

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    ...
}
```

in my BLL might fill each user up with its data before it is added to the collection?

Really hoping someone can give me an "a ha" moment here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the right approach, creating classes for those supporting entities (although I'd put `StateOrProvince` in a separate `Address` entity, and maybe all those traits in a separate `PersonTraits` entity).

There're many ways to solve this. Without an ORM, take a look at [Data Mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) (also at [Dependent Mapping](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dependentMapping.html)), which could be used to map from a database query to a `Person` instance. This is an outline of the mapper code:

```
var row = ... // query database
var person = new Person(row["FirstName"], row["LastName"]);
person.EyeColor = new EyeColor(row["EyeColorID"], row["EyeColorName"]);
...
```

(You could also use some kind of separate [Object Builder](http://nat.truemesh.com/archives/000714.html).)

Anytime you update a person, you update all supporting information as well using the ID of the related entities.

**UPDATE**: an ORM like EF4 is very powerful and would help you with a lot of repetitive tasks (like the mapping I've described). The important thing is to keep your architecture flexible and have persistency as just one swappable layer. Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx) for some guidance. Also, I found that the book "Domain Driven Design" is really important to understand this kind of separation and how to model your entities.

Comment: Thanks you. Encapsulating StateOrProvince in an Address class is right on the money. I think that would have been my next logical step once I actually started building this. I never would have thought to go a step farther with "PersonTraits" though because it is such a big step away from the DB schema. I guess I'm too used to thinking in terms of my SQL model that I can't free my mind to think in an object model.

Comment: Would you suggest that I use an ORM? I messed with EF4 as a DAL on a previous test site about 6 months ago... but I don't think I was quite mentally ready for it. I'm almost getting to a point with my understanding of OOP that it might make more sense to me now.

Comment: Sure, an ORM like EF4 is very powerful and would help you with a lot of repetitive tasks (like the mapping I've described). The important thing is to keep your architecture flexible and have persistency as just one swappable layer. Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx) for some guidance. Also, I found that the book "Domain Driven Design" is really important to understand this kind of separation and how to model your entities.

Comment: @Jordão: Update your answer with your suggestion of EF4. ...+1 for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would mirror your lookup tables as enums.  Then you get both the id and name in a single value.  If names include characters that can not be used in an identifier then you can easily create an attribute to handle the additional data.

**Additional Info** (eg Example Code, modify to suit, I write in VB so conversion to C# will be nessecary):

```
Namespace Company.Data
  Public Enum EyeColor As Int16
    Unknown = 0
    Brown = 1
    Blue = 2
    Green = 3
  End Enum

  Public Enum HairColor As Int16
    Unknown = 0
    Brown = 1
    Blond = 2
    Red = 3
    Pink = 4
  End Enum
End Namespace



Public Class Person

  Public Property EyeColor As EyeColor = EyeColor.Unknown

  Public Property HairColor As HairColor = HairColor.Unknown

End Class
```

Since you are using enums the individual enum values map to your database lookup table keys.  So you can get your Display with `aPersonObject.HairColor.ToString()`, and you can get the ID with `aPersonObject.HairColor`

You can get really fancy and use some code-gen (mabey T4 templates) to create your enums automatically from the values in the database.

Comment: I really appreciate your input but I'm too obtuse to understand it at this moment. I've used enums... but mostly just as constants for Case statement decisions. Is there a way you can ammend your response to have a little sample code that might flip my "a ha" switch? If I had a Person.cs file and a PersonManager.cs file which contained static methods like GetPeople() or GetPerson()... where would these enums live... and how would they integrate with my Person class?

Comment: added some additional content.  If you need more clarification let me know.

Comment: The whole point of a foreign key is so that the list is contained in the data store, not hardcover.

Comment: @BenVoigt: no, the whole point of a foreign key is data integrity and consistency.  Especially in this case where the lookup tables will be pre-loaded with all the possible values.  If the foreign key table was to be updated often I would certainly not recommend enums.  But in this case it seems the best option to me.

Comment: @Boo: There are cheaper ways to enforce a range constraint if all the valid values are known apriori.  I see nothing in this question to suggest the lookup tables are unchanging.

Comment: The nature of the data and the fact that they are in "lookup tables" suggests their staticness.  And this isn't about range constraints.  This is about key/value pairs and a simple mechanism for accessing both the key and the value on the application side of things while enforcing data integrity/consistency on the database side.

Comment: Thanks guys. Admittedly in this specific example the lookups are pretty clearly on the static side... but I'd still prefer to not have to recompile if I ever did change something. Ideally whatever "pattern" I end up with would be used on other potentially more volatile lookup table values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into "navigation property" in EF? It'll allow you to keep the IDs in the main class (i.e. Person) and reference the string properties via navigation properties. For example, you'll have:

Person p = [get record from EF data context]

p.state_id will refer to the numeric ID of the state whereas p.State.Name will be the string name of the state. EF takes care of loading the referenced state record. It can even create them for you automatically if you use database-first and have your foreign keys defined (there are tools that'll convert database-first to code-first)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would have my presentation layer talking directly to EF entities, right? I prefer to avoid that as I mentioned in the beginning of the question (the context area). From the research I've done I've ascertained that it's a best practice for my business layer to be an abstraction away from the persistence layer. Presentation --> business --> persistence. I think the very act of me trying to use the SQL IDs breaks this model... but it's not as "bad" as my presentation layer talking directly to entities? I'm no expert obviously... but that's what I gather.

Comment: Yes you can have them talking to the EF entities however with code-first, your EF entities are just POCO classes that are no different than if you had written them yourself. Yeah you could create a complete hierarchy of classes at your presentation layer but why do that when the presentation classes will be *exactly* the same as the  POCO EF Entities. You can put the EF POCO classes into a separate assembly and have that be the vehicle for exchanging data btw all the different layers.

Comment: Take a look at this tool for creating POCOs from EDMX: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d